# Como jogar logs da gem Audited no Logstash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Qual o melhor caminho para jogar os logs da `gem Audited` (rails para o *Logstash* ?

A `Gem Audited`: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. O idioma oficial usado aqui é o Português, você poderia traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Obrigado, não reparei que estava no Pt.